PowerAutomate - While using 'Get Records' action with 'LastModifiedDate' filter, some records are missing in the output
From PowerAutomate while using  Get Records action with 'LastModifiedDate' filter,
some records are missing in the output of Power Automate 'Get Records' action even though they fall within the specified date range.With tool 'Execute a SOQL query' all matching records are fetched. Have anyone faced this issue.
Have tried to replicate this issue by creating a trial account in Salesforce.
But was unable to create a Salesforce account. Wanted to know if this issue is coming from salesforce api returning less number of records.
